# Should I encrypt username/email fields in my MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I am encrypting fields in the database, but I don't think i can encrypt the user's `username` or `email` because I use those fields to find the user. I could hash them instead, but since I don't think I can use a unique salt per username/email someone could just use a rainbow table to find the hidden username/email.

I guess this it is ok to not encrypt them? I would like to make the website as secure as possible. Would hashing them make sense? I could find a user by their `_id` instead of `username`/`email`, but I wouldn't have their `_id` until I find the user.

What I am doing currently:

```
const user = await new db.userModel({
    email: email,
    username: username,
    stuff: cryptr.encrypt(stuff),
});

////

const user = await db.userModel.findOne({
    email: email
}).exec();
```

EDIT: I guess hashing would not make sense, since I cannot un-hash the username/email. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this it is ok to not encrypt them?

In most cases, yes. Passwords should be hashed (+ salt..) and sensitive data should be encrypted. But username or email in most cases should not be sensitive.

---

But let's assume they will be encrypted in DB.

You are storing `encrypt(username)` in your DB, so in order to search for that, instead of using `username`, use `encrypt(username)`. Of course sorting may cause some headaches, but finding the user should be efficient.

---

Think of encrypting (in your case) not about hackers, but about people who are reading those records. For example developers who are investigating a production issue or a DBA, you want some (not all) fields hard for them to read. Storing the key on a different machine, best in a Key Management Tool, will add an extra security layer.

Comment: I tried searching for `encrypt(username)`, but `encrypt(username)` returns a different encrypted string for the same text input, which makes it impossible. :/

Comment: encryption algorithms are mostly if not all deterministic, do you have a lead maybe on why this is happening? (like do you apply salt?)

Comment: Jefla not sure. I'm using cryptr, which is basically NodeJS's crypto module.

Comment: the library you are using generates a random IV which causes it to be non-deterministic. https://codeforgeek.com/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-node-js/ has an example, just reuse the `key` and `iv` and the encrypted string will be the same. Not using a random IV will make it more vulnerable for hackers for example, but the for the DBA example, it will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

This question should really be asked on infosec Stackexchange.

Encryption is usually pointless as a defense against hackers, because you need to access the key to use the encrypted database. That means that you need to save it next to the database. If your server becomes compromised, then the hacker will simply decrypt the database with the key. Of course it's better than doing nothing, because it is possible (maybe improbable) that the hacker will compromise only the database. Horatiu Jeflea hovewer mentions other important reasons to encrypt the database, which you should especially consider if you are not working on the project alone.

Hashing usernames is only possible if you don't need to display them, but usernames are usually public anyway, so it improves security very little.

Hashing emails is an interesting problem. You asked for them for a reason. You presumably need to contact your users. If you hash them, you won't be able to do it and if you don't need to do it, then you don't need to (and shouldn't) save them in the first place. If however they are only part of the authentication process, then it would be possible solution.

Rainbow tables can't really break modern hashing algorithms, although the biggest mitigation is aforementioned salt, which will make it *MUCH* harder for most attack on the hash. You also have to make sure that you are not using vulnerable ones like md5, but safe one like sha256 or sufficient bcrypt. You should hash the passwords with one of those. Also note that you could use the same salt for all the hashed fields and the salt could even be (this would reduce the security little bit) one of the public fields (username?). There are very little excuses for not using salt.

In summary: you can't hash them and encryption is probably not worth it unless you can sufficiently isolate the key, or need it because of something else than external hackers